# How to custom jquery mobile select widget outlook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, widget

For example, I want the title is on the left side inside the button.

Image sample: http://oi57.tinypic.com/iy3ebm.jpg

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/ejkcnpvo/

```
<select name="select_choice" id="select_choice" title="Location">
  <option value="1">San Francisco</option>
  <option value="2">Hong Kong</option>
  <option value="3">China</option>
  <option value="4">Japan</option>
</select>
```

I want to extend current select widget instead of "hard code".

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can obtain the value of an attribute such as `title` using:

```
$(selector).attr("title");
```

In your example, the `select` item's title could be found with:

```
var title = $("#select_choice").attr("title");
```

Now that you have the title, you can add your text to the DOM prior to the `select`.  For example:

```
$("#select_choice").prepend($("<span>" + title + "</span>");
```

For more details on each of these APIs, see the relevant section in the jQuery online documentation.

Comment: I want to extend current select widget instead of "hard code".

Comment: The way that one would "extend" jQuery provided functions would be to write new CSS and JavaScript, place that in a web accessible file and have that loaded by the browser.  Whether this new logic/code is "hard coded" in the original HTML source file or in a JavaScript file that is loaded by the HTML source file at runtime, the result will be the same.